# Github - It's possible to configure "pipeline must succeed"?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to require a pipeline successful to allow merge to master, there's a way this can be done on github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by selecting settings in your repo and then selecting branches. you will find `Branch protection rules` and from there you can click on `add branch protection rule` and add a status check using `Require status checks to pass before merging`.

You can add a status check rule to check for a successful pipeline.

Comment: I see @MAE but how I could implement a check for a successful pipeline?

Comment: As soon as the pipeline was run for the first time, you should see it as an option in the "status checks" dropdown. Please note that you need to type a few characters in order to make that list show something :)

Comment: Hey @rethab you were right typing some characters made that list show some stuff like the workflow name and some steps. So setting the workflow name to the status check should be the right choice?